# EF6 Code First - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework Code First 6.  I made some basic changes to my entities now I am unable to scaffold.  I'm getting the error below.  I even tried reverting my code to when I could scaffold and I get the same error.  I have steps that I've taken in the past to completely reset code first (delete the database, Enable-Migrations -force, ...) but that is also not working.  Any ideas how I can get past this error?

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntitySetMapping..ctor(EntitySet entitySet, EntityContainerMapping containerMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.AddEntitySetMapping(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntitySet entitySet)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel conceptualModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  Had a poorly named Entity "Timezone" that I ended up removing because I did not need it.  However, I left the virtual property "Timezone" in another entity.  VS compiled it fine because it thought it was a system class but EF code first threw an error on it.